# angular2 More than one component error

Tags: angular, components

i just upgrade my ng2 app from rc.4 to rc.5. 
what in my app.html is:

```
<div>
    <switch-app [account]="cache.accountInfo" [app]="cache.current_app">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

i declare the SwitchAppComponent at app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ]
    declarations: [
        SwitchAppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

then this error has occurred:

```
More than one component: AppComponent,SwitchAppComponent

[ERROR ->]<switch-app [account]="cache.accountInfo" [app]="cache.current_app"></switch-app>
```

i checked my app, the selector of AppComponent and SwitchAppComponent is difference.

here is a brief codes of the two component:
app-component:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app]',
    styleUrls: ['./app.css', './custom.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './app.html'
})
export class AppComponent extends CommonComponent implements OnInit {

    cache = cache;
}
```

switch-app component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'switch-app',
    templateUrl: './switch-app.html'
})
export class SwitchAppComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('app') app;
    @Input('account') account;
    ngOnInit() { console.log(this.account, this.app);}
}
```

Comment: i found the problem, cause i declare my AppComponent with an attribute [app], but when i insert the switch-app component into it, i use an [app] attribute as Input of it. as long as i change the [app] attr of switch-app, all thing is right

Answer (score 6):

The issue is there:

```
 <switch-app [account]="cache.accountInfo" [app]="cache.current_app"></switch-app>
```

This matches both the `switch-app` selector, and the `[app]` selector, both being selectors for a component. Angular cannot use 2 components on the same element.

Not sure what you are trying to do here, maybe one component should be a directive instead ?